# Fetch() method fails to output - Smarty

Tags: smarty, fetch

I am using the fetch() method to store a template and display it within another as so :

```
    $this->mySmarty->assign('template',$this->fetch('template.tpl'));
    $this->display('mypage.html');
```

where mySmarty was instantiated as a smarty class. The I call {$template} inside mypage.html.

The page "mypage.html" displays correctly but the {$template} variable outputs 0. How can it be ? (knowing I set the permissions correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Mystery, I managed to come over the problem by this trick : $template = $this->fetch('template.tpl'); $this->mySmarty->assign('template',$template);